# How to move post into specific location using firebase database on android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making android app using firebase database. On recyclerview page, I made some change to display posts in reverse mode so now it can display latest on top of the page.

I want to make functionality that can move any post in recyclerview to the last of recyclerview page.

For example, if I click the post on recylervew, it will go to page that can see more detail. On the page, there is button called "read". what this button will do is that when I click the read-button. it will make post in recylerview move to the last of recyclerview page. so user can not see the post unless user scroll all the way down to the recyclerview page. and I want to apply this functionality on any post in the recyclerview page.

I am not familiar with firebase database so I have no idea how to make this work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private BibleAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Bible> arrayList;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
public static final String VERSE_DATA="data";
public static final int REQUEST_CODE=101;
public static final String HOLDER="holder";
public static final String POSITION="position";
public static final String ARRAYLIST="arraylist";
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager; //for sorting


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, 
  container, false);


    //GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
   GridLayoutManager(getContext(),  2);

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   //layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    //mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = database.getReference("Bible");

    adapter = new BibleAdapter(arrayList, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
    ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Bible bible = snapshot.getValue(Bible.class);
                arrayList.add(bible);

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.e("fragment1", 
   String.valueOf(databaseError.toException()));//에러문 출력
        }
    });

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnVerseItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder holder, View 
   view, int position) {
           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "num"+adapter.getItemCount(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Verse.class);
            Bible verse = new Bible(arrayList.get(position).getImage(), 
  arrayList.get(position).getBibleType(),
                    arrayList.get(position).getVerse(), 
   arrayList.get(position).getContent(), 
   arrayList.get(position).getKeysentance());
            intent.putExtra(VERSE_DATA, verse);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

public class BibleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private  ArrayList<Bible> arrayList;
private  Context context;
private OnVerseItemClickListener listener;

public BibleAdapter(ArrayList<Bible> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnVerseItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.verse_item, parent, false);
    BibleViewHolder holder = new BibleViewHolder(view, listener);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(holder.imageView)
            .load(arrayList.get(position).getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.bibleType.setText(arrayList.get(position).getBibleType());
    holder.keysentance.setText(arrayList.get(position).getKeysentance());
    holder.verse.setText(arrayList.get(position).getVerse());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (arrayList!=null? arrayList.size():0);
}


public class BibleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView bibleType;
    TextView verse;
    TextView keysentance;

    public BibleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnVerseItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.bibleType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bibleType);
        this.keysentance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.keysentance);
        this.verse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.verse);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onItemClick(BibleViewHolder.this, v, position);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentCallback{

```
Fragment1 fragment1;
Fragment2 fragment2;
Fragment3 fragment3;

Toolbar toolbar;

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragment3 = new Fragment3();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment1).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.menu1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "첫번째 메뉴 선택됨.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onFragmentSelected(0, null);
    }else if(id == R.id.menu2){
        Toast.makeText(this, "두번째 메뉴 선택됨.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onFragmentSelected(1, null);
    }else if(id == R.id.menu3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "세번째 메뉴 선택됨.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        onFragmentSelected(2, null);
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onFragmentSelected(int position, Bundle bundle) {
    Fragment curFragment = null;

    if(position == 0){
        curFragment = fragment1;
        toolbar.setTitle("첫번째 화면");
    }else if(position == 1){
        curFragment = fragment2;
        toolbar.setTitle("두번째 화면");
    }else if(position == 2){
        curFragment = fragment3;
        toolbar.setTitle("세번째 화면");
       }
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
    curFragment).commit();
  }
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: I made posts displayed in reserved order so far

Comment: Add that code to your question so we can take a look at it.

Comment: I just edited post